# D3 with Topojson only renders parts of the map

Tags: javascript, d3.js, topojson

I'm trying to create a choropleth map of USA and color it according to some data. So, I get data (just json files):

```
d3.queue()
.defer(d3.json, 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/no-stack-dub-sack/testable-projects-fcc/master/src/data/choropleth_map/counties.json')
.defer(d3.json, 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/no-stack-dub-sack/testable-projects-fcc/master/src/data/choropleth_map/for_user_education.json')
.await(ready);
```

Then in my ready function I do this

```
function ready(error, us, education) {
  if (error) throw error;

  svg.append("g").selectAll( "path" )
  .data(topojson.feature(us, us.objects.counties).features)
  .enter()
  .append( "path" )
  .attr("class", "county")
  .attr( "fill", "red" )
  .attr( "d", path )
```

(My `path` variable is defined on top of the file `const path = d3.geoPath();`)

And I get my map, but there are some kind of holes in it, like some counties just don't render. I haven't implemented the coloring yet, so it should all just be red, but has big black fragments (which also don't react to `mouseover`). You can see it on my CodePen: http://codepen.io/enk/pen/dNBOoj

Please, tell me where is my mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is in  your mesh:

```
   svg.append("path")
      .datum(topojson.mesh(us, us.objects.states, function(a, b) { return a !== b; }))
      .attr("class", "states")
      .attr("d", path);
```

You need to specify a fill of none for it in your css:

```
.states {
  fill:none;
}
```

or in the code that appends it:

```
   svg.append("path")
      .datum(topojson.mesh(us, us.objects.states, function(a, b) { return a !== b; }))
      .attr("class", "states")
      .attr('fill','none')
      .attr("d", path);
```

[Updated pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oBrWxM).

Comment: Thank you so much!